# Finding bounds for triple integral

Tags: integration

Let $S$ be the solid bounded by $$4x^2 +y^2 = 4, z+x=2, z=0$$, find the bounds for the triple integral of any function $f$ in the order $dzdydx$. The answers were that the bounds were $$0 \leq z \leq 2-x, -2\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq x \leq 2\sqrt{1-x^2}, -1 \leq y \leq 1 .$$
What I don't get is, suppose I couldn't draw the diagram (which I couldn't), how would I have known this? I thought we would have to solve the first and second equations simultaneously for an equation in terms of z and y, and then find bounds from there... but apparently not. How come?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to visualize I agree. Let's take the 3 equations separately and I assume that the $x$-$y$ plan is horizontal and the $z$ axis is vertical in space :

- $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$. We know this is an ellipse that has $x$-radius" $1$ and $y$-radius $2$. Since there is no constraint on $z$. It ranges over the whole space. So now in our mind we should have the idea of a long elliptical cylinder that is vertically unbounded.
- $z=0$. Clearly this is a plan and it is simply the $x$-$y$ plan. So this gives us a flat bottom to our cylinder.
- $x+z=2$. This will be the top of our cylinder. Unfortunately it is not flat. However it doesn't depend on $y$. So this means that if we fix some $y$ in our cylinder, the value will be constant there. Hence the cork of the cylinder will be a tilted plan "parallel" to the $y$-axis

Now based on that we need to chose the "free" variable, $x,y$ or $z$, that will range between fix number. Clearly $z$ is a bad choice since the cork is tilted and depends on $x$. So lets choose $x$ which ranges from $-1$ to $1$ according to the ellipse.

Then based on $x$ we can parameterize the cylinder as the equation suggests. (Solve $4x^2 + y^2 = 4$ for $y$. Note that you might have a typo in your question.)

Finally we need make $z$ ranges. Clearly it starts at the bottom of the cylinder at $0$ and then depending on $x$ goes to the tilted top. (Solve $x+z=2$ for $z$)

Comment: Much appreciated! What I don't get is basically because I can't visualise it. What if the $x+z=2$ equation "splits" the region of integration for the last integral $dx$ up into two regions? Similar to say, a double integral with a region that looks like a trapezium, which clearly would need to split up depending on what order of integration we choose.  
Also, sometimes we would have to solve simultaenously for the range of our free variables, but why not in this case?

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems that projecting just the $z-x$ plane on a 2-d plane makes it helpful. Is it just in this case?